# How to pass parameters to async function in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async.js

I'm Trying to take a screenshot from a website using the package [puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/)

For this I create a simple server with Express:

```
app.get('/requestScreenShootForDesktop/:id', function(req, res){
    (async () => {
        const pathUpload = 'uploads/' + Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + '.png';
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.goto(this.req.params.id);
        await page.setViewport({width: 1920, height: 1080});
        await page.screenshot({path: pathUpload});

        await browser.close();
        await res.send({msg: 'ScreenShot Ok'});
      })();
});
```

The problem with this code is on line `await page.goto(this.req.params.id);`, Node says:

> Cannot read property 'params' of undefined

This is because the variable `req` belonging to function `app.get` doesn't exists in async scope.

How can I solve this problem, and pass my variable to async function ?

Comment: Why are you using a self invoking function?

Comment: The problem is not that `req` doesn't exist, it's that `this.req` doesn't exist. Why did you use `this`? Overall it's not really clear what you intend for that code to do.

Comment: This is just a typo: `this.req` should be `req`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just ditch the IIFE and dont use `this` to access `req`

```
app.get('/requestScreenShootForDesktop/:id', async function(req, res){
    const pathUpload = 'uploads/' + Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + '.png';
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.goto(req.params.id);
    await page.setViewport({width: 1920, height: 1080});
    await page.screenshot({path: pathUpload});

    await browser.close();

    res.send({msg: 'ScreenShot Ok'});
});
```

Comment: What should that change?

Comment: my bad I had missed the usage of `this`

Comment: That is still a typo?

Comment: whats a typo? please explain or better yet, answer

Comment: `this.res` vs `res`. Thats just a typo.

Comment: IIFE is not a typo though

Answer (score 0):

```
(async (req, res) => {
    const pathUpload = 'uploads/' + Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + '.png';
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(req.params.id);
    await page.setViewport({width: 1920, height: 1080});
    await page.screenshot({path: pathUpload});

    await browser.close();
    await res.send({msg: 'ScreenShot Ok'});
  })(req, res);
```

Comment: There is no sense in using `req` and `res` as parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep IIFE, but remove `this` keyword